# Why WordPress architecture is not pure object oriented and it don't use MVC pattern?

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, customization, development-strategy

I am pretty new in WordPress and PHP development (I came from Java and C#) and I am a bit
astonished about how WP is structured.

Coming from Java and C# I'm used to work on totally object oriented architectures and now, working on WP, it seems to me that it is not totaly object oriented.

For example the **function.php** file ino every theme is not a class but is a simple php file containing some functions, so it respect the old procedural model.

At the same time it seems to me that WP don't use MVC pattern

My question is: why WordPress (that is a modern CMS) don't use a totally Object Oriented paradigm and don't adopt the MVC model?

Comment: It's an important & good question, but I'm afraid this isn't the place for it. I'm fairly certain all of the core team will be on the [wp-hackers mailing list](http://lists.automattic.com/mailman/listinfo/wp-hackers), so I think trying there might be better.

Comment: One view: [Gloves aren't for feet](http://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-and-mvc/). (Also read the first comment on that article.)

Comment: WordPress isn't a modern CMS, it's a legacy CMS that sees active and continued development. Sadly the only person who can accurately answer this has been gone so long that when he was last around WordPress hadn't been founded ( b2 maintainer )

Comment: Failing that, Matt Mullenweg or Mike Little may be the next best able people to answer this, both of which are available via twitter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WordPress as a project has extreme commitment to backwards compatibility. Whatever new things you add the old things need to work still. Whatever things you change still need to work in old *way* as well.

So regardless of how WP started as non–MVC application, it cannot become one without retaining all of its non–MVC ways. Which makes it pretty pointless direction.

Coming from formal background MVC might seem like a baseline and "naturally" preferable way to organize. Coming from self–taught background (or lack of programming background entirely) it's mostly overblown abstraction which even people who like it cannot agree on.

WordPress largely targets *users*, not *developers*. Any complicating of the learning curve will just be shooting its strong sides for little gain.

Comment: Interesting point of view